# Group-wise operation by factor in data frame

Tags: r

Consider the following data frame

```
 ## Example data frame
    z1<-c("a", "b", "c", "c", "b", "a", "a", "b", "c") ##groups
    z2<-c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z") ##experiments
    z3<-c(2,4,8,15,9,3,1,2,3)                          ##results
    df<-data.frame(group=z1, id=z2, res=z3)            ##z1, z2, and z3 to data frame
```

I'd like to automatically generate the column (`z4`), which is the fold change for the data in `z3`.

The calculation I would like to perform is:

> a/a & b/a & c/a for id=x and c/a & b/a & c/a for id=y etc.

and add the results in a new column of the data frame.

i.e.,

```
df$z4 <- c(1,2,4,5,3,1,1,2,3) ## by hand
```

My line of thought was that I should break the problem down with something like:

```
###function to check whether group=a, returns TRUE/FALSE
checkA<-function(x){
  if(x=="a"){
    res=TRUE
  }else {
    res=FALSE
  }
return(res)
}

### checks whether a is in df$group
df$check<-lapply(df$group, checkA)
```

But it did not really help. I have the feeling that this can be done with built-in functions (one of the `apply`s or `ifelse`) but I cannot get my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `by` to apply a function to subsets of data:

```
df$z4 <- unlist(by(df, df$id, FUN = function(x) x$res / x$res[x$group == "a"]))

df
  group id res z4
1     a  x   2  1
2     b  x   4  2
3     c  x   8  4
4     c  y  15  5
5     b  y   9  3
6     a  y   3  1
7     a  z   1  1
8     b  z   2  2
9     c  z   3  3
```